# sending an array by GET to a web service with jquery

Tags: jquery, web-services

I have this form:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="cen" runat="server">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Contacto</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Hora</th>
                    <th >Mensaje</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>                        
                    <td><input name="user[]" id="correo" type="email" placeholder="contacto@correo.com" style="width: 10em;"></td>
                    <td><input name="date[]" id="fecha" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}'></td>
                    <td><input name="hour[]" id="hora" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "overrideTimeFormat": 12}'></td>
                    <td><textarea name="mensaje[]" id="mensaje" placeholder="Su mensaje Aqui" style="width: 15em; max-width: 15em;"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </form>
```

I have a button to clone that form, so the user can send an array of elements.

My question: how do I send that array to a Web service with JQuery? I have this for the moment:

```
<script>
        $("form").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var result = new XMLHttpRequest;
            var URL = "checkMessage.ashx?sendTo=" + $('#correo').val() + "&dateIn=" + $('#fecha').val() + "&hourIn=" + $('#hora').val() + "&messageIn=" + $('#mensaje');
            result.open("GET", URL, false);
            result.send;
            var resultString = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
           // var resultString = JSON.parse(result.responseText);

            if (resultString.respuesta == 1)
            {
                alert("Su mensaje fue enviado");
            }
        })
    </script>
```

But the web service doesn't receive anything.

For the moment in my web service I just have these:

```
 public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    string[] destinatario;
    string respuesta;
    respuesta = context.Request.QueryString["sendTo"];}
```

Because I making test.

This is the first time I'm working with web service.

My problem is, that I can't consume the web service, and I don't know wy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jQuery anyway, why would you write your own ajax function, when jQuery has an excellent cross browser `$.ajax` function ?

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url : 'checkMessage.ashx',
        data: {
            sendTo: $('#correo').val(),
            dateIn: $('#fecha').val(),
            hourIn: $('#hora').val(),
            messageIn: $('#mensaje').val()
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

I'm guessing your webserver is set up to receive GET requests, and use the data your sending, and as you haven't included any code for that, it's impossible to answer ?

Also note that on the last parameter `"&messageIn=" + $('#mensaje');` you're trying to send a DOM element, and that wont work.

Comment: I alredy edit the question... Why don't gonna work? I having troubles with all these, this is the first time I'm working with all these

Answer (score 0):

To send it to a webservice, you should use `POST` instead of `GET`.

Comment: But, how I send the array? Because my problem is that, I don't know how to send the array to the Web Service